# Reading images in multiple folders

Tags: python, file, path

I am facing a problem with reading images on multiple files. I have a file like this:

[image: file directory]

Now, I want to read all images in file rgb, but in file rgb also have 3 folders(00,01,02) that containing images in this. How can I read all images in 3 folders 00,01,02. Furthermore, in the folder annotation, I also have 3 folders named 00, 01, and 02, but in these 3 folders, it contains 2 kind of files which is txt and npy. I just want to read txt file, what should I do?
The images in "rgb" file I will use to train the model, and txt files will be used as labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pathlib.Path()` allows wildcards to match what your are looking for.  `**` is a wildcard that matches "all subdirectories", and `*` matches anything in the filename:

```py
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('Videos frame')

for f in p.glob('rgb/**/*.png'): # or whatever your image type is...
    print(f)

for f in p.glob('annotation/**/*.txt'):
    print(f)
```

Comment: I want to load images in rgb folder into a list X_data, then load txt file from annotation folder into Y_data, but I do not know if images in X_data correspond to labels( .txt is the labels in my data) in Y_data or not. What should I do?

Comment: I have added images to X_data list, its range is 1467, but range of Y_data is 1466( and 1 .txt file is empty) what should I do to have each image in X_data corresponds to labels in Y_data?

Comment: @HaiLuu Ask a new question. Show the code you have so far.

Comment: Yes, I have posted a new one