# Loading images into a list and its corresponding lables [Python]

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning

I have a problem when loading images in one folder and their labels in another folder.
This is my old post about it:
[Reading images in multiple folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66378242/reading-images-in-multiple-folders/66378362?noredirect=1#comment117368324_66378362)
I have loaded images into a variable X_data, and its labels into Y_data. However, their range is not the same. Furthermore, an element in Y_data is empty. What should I do to be sure that each image has its correct labels?

```
p = Path('Carla_Videos')
myFolderList = [f.path for f in os.scandir(path) if f.is_dir()]
X_data = []
Y_data = []
for files in p.glob('rgb/**/*.jpg'):
    #print(files)
    img = cv2.imread(str(files))
    X_data.append(img)
    #splitted_path = files.replace('.jpg','').sp
    # print(img_path)
for f in p.glob('annotation/**/*.txt'):
    labels = np.loadtxt(str(f))
    Y_data.append(labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this sample directory structure base on your previous question:

```
├───annotation
│   ├───00
│   │       file1.txt
│   │       file2.txt
│   └───01
│           file3.txt
└───rgb
    ├───00
    │       file1.jpg
    │       file2.jpg
    └───01
            file3.jpg
            file4.jpg
```

This code will locate `.jpg` files, compute the matching annotation, and check that the annotation exists:

```py
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('.')

for image in p.glob('rgb/**/*.jpg'):
    text = 'annotation' / image.relative_to('rgb').with_suffix('.txt')
    print(image,text,text.is_file())
```

Output:

```
rgb\00\file1.jpg annotation\00\file1.txt True
rgb\00\file2.jpg annotation\00\file2.txt True
rgb\01\file3.jpg annotation\01\file3.txt True
rgb\01\file4.jpg annotation\01\file4.txt False
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and I got an error: ValueError: 'Carla_Videos\\rgb\\000\\00.jpg' does not start with 'rgb'

Comment: @HaiLuu I started with the current directory as `p`.  Make `Carla_videos` the current directory or use `'Carla_videos/annotations' / image.relative_to('Carla_videos/rgb')` instead. Read the `pathlib` documentation and learn how the methods work.